# Rational analysis

Tags: analysis, rational-numbers

I found myself thinking about how much of real analysis that can also be developed within the rational numbers. Of course, $\Bbb Q$ is lacking what is perhaps the most important property of the real numbers, the Cauchy completeness (or, equivalently, the existence of the least upper bound). But still, it appears you could get quite far in $\Bbb Q$. First of all, elementary notions like continuity, limits and differentiability are easily definable (though even among the real functions that can be restricted to operators on $\Bbb Q$, not all of them will satisfy these definitions). Riemann integrability can also be defined in a limited form: In real analysis, the definition of the integral involves the supremum and the infimum. But we *can* define rational Riemann integrability *if* the upper and lower bounds in question do exist in $\Bbb Q$ and satisfy the appropriate relations, which will of course often be the case. But obviously, a function like $\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}\ni x\mapsto 1/x$ is *not* integrable, since $\int_a^b \tfrac 1 x d x = \log(\tfrac b a)$ is not rational for unequal $a,b\in\Bbb Q$. But still, it seems we *can* get quite far.

Does someone have an impression of *how* far we can get? Also, I have been totally unable to find any mention of rational analysis, as poor as it may be, in literature. Seeing that how far I could get, I find that strange. Does someone have an opinion about why this is the case.

Comment: [Timothy Gowers wrote an excellent article that's related to this question.](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/reals.html)

Comment: You can't prove anything interesting without the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I can't say I agree. I consider theorems like the Inverse Function Theorem to be interesting. This holds as a corollary to the corresponding statement in real analysis since the inverse of a rational function is rational.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387234/how-far-can-one-get-in-analysis-without-leaving-mathbbq/413126#413126

Comment: @Gaussler: I don't know what you mean by "the inverse of a rational function is rational." By "rational function" do you mean a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which sends $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$? If so, this is clearly false; for example, $x \mapsto x^3$ is rational but its inverse isn't.

Comment: I think I had an idea that we could restrict the function to a subset of $\Bbb Q$ and obtain what we wanted. But you're right, never mind what I just said. :-P