# Necessity of the Completeness Axiom in Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

A friend asked me today why we need to bother with the Completeness Axiom in calculus. Even though I have taken a real analysis course quite a while ago, I could not answer him and I realized I had the same question.

The Completeness "Axiom" for $\mathbb{R}$, or equivalently, the least upper bound property, is introduced early in a course in real analysis. It is then shown that it can be used to prove the Archimedean property, is related to concept of Cauchy sequences and so on.

Let's consider a formal proof of the limit of a function, the simplest I can think of:
To prove $\lim_{x\to1} 2x = 2$, take $\delta=\epsilon/2$. Then $|x-1|<\epsilon/2$ implies $|2x-2|<\epsilon$ and the proof is complete.

The "Completeness Axiom" must be implicitly assumed somewhere in this short proof - where? This also hopefully explains why we can't take this kind of limit in $\mathbb{Q}$.

**EDIT**: According to a comment, it seems this limit proof does not require the Completeness Axiom. Since the derivative and the Riemann integral can be defined using limits, that begs the question: Is it possible to have differential and integral calculus based only on $\mathbb{Q}$? If so, what are the most significant results that would no longer hold (the Intermediate Value Theorem for example, as mentioned in the Answers)?

Comment: In fact, this argument makes perfect sense in $ \mathbb{Q} $.

Comment: Thanks Berrick Fillmore - could you take a look at the new edit in the question?

Comment: Hi TSJ. Suppose that we have a bounded function $ f: \Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{Q} $. If we define its Riemann integral over $ [a,b] $, where $ a,b \in \Bbb{Q} $ and $ a < b $, to be the limit of some sort of sequence built using rational numbers only, then the convergence of the sequence is not guaranteed even if it is Cauchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ is the completeness axiom. So any property which is true in $\mathbb R$ but not in $\mathbb Q$ needs the completeness axiom. If you proof for example the existence of $\sqrt 2$ you will need the completeness axiom somewhere in your proof (otherwise you could prove $\sqrt 2 \in \mathbb Q$).

Now you can think of all theorems like the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) which hold for $\mathbb R$ as your basic number system but not for $\mathbb Q$. You will not have these theorems if you do not have the completeness axiom...

**EDIT:** Please have a look at these threads for your additional question:

- [How far can one get in analysis without leaving Q?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387234/how-far-can-one-get-in-analysis-without-leaving-mathbbq)
- [Do we really need reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078593/do-we-really-need-reals)

Comment: Thanks tempis - could you take a look at the edits in the question?

Comment: @TSJ: See my edit...

Comment: +1 for the links in the edits.